# Layout with sidebar

Tags: html, css, layout

I can't get my layout to work the way it want it to...

I have an `position:absolute` `header`, a `float:left` `aside` sidebar and a `position:absolute` `div#page`

Now, whatever I try I can't get the sidebar to extend all the way down to the bottom of the page.

EDIT:
here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/JY9y9/

Comment: Post more HTML and CSS.  Put it in a fiddle if possible.

Comment: The site that @zero298 is referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JY9y9/

Comment: you could do height: 100vh; more info here http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths. Be advised though, not supported for > IE 8

Answer (score 0):

try adding `position:absolute; min-height: 100%;` to your `.sidebar` selector.

Check this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JY9y9/6/

Answer (score -1):

I made this for you:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    hello
</aside>
<div id='page'>
hello
</div>

.sidebar{
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    padding: 0 0 3em 0;
    width: 37%;
    background-color:#333;
    color: #fff;
    height:100%;
}

#page{
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:39%;
    width: 61%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9V2r/2/?

It might be a done a bit quick and messy but it works. I hope i understood correctly and this helped you! :D